# "452: out of range pointer" during installation - Why? And how to fix it?

Tags: grub2, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 23.04 on a newly-assembled home server (just a mini-PC with 32GB of RAM), but whatever entry I select (install, safe graphics, test memory) I get the "out of range pointer" error. I'm using a physical, non-ARM machine.

The specifics are:

- AMD Ryzen 5 5600G (integrated graphics)
- 32GB (16GBx2) of RAM @ 3200MHz
- M.2 500GB disk

I've tried googling around, but the only relevant result was about an updated installation no longer working, nothing about an ongoing one.

Please, be very specific and detailed with your instructions or if you need more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/) fixed this in version 4.0. From [Rufu's changelog at GitHub](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/blob/master/ChangeLog.txt):

> Fix out-of-range pointer error with Ubuntu 23.04 when booting in BIOS mode

Comment: Yeah, the root of the problem is that because GRUB (the bootloader that is actually generating the error) is not releasing in a timely manner, the Ubuntu people have been cherry-picking patches from the upcoming GRUB codebase, and these patches were not included in the **vanilla** GRUB 2.06 version provided by Rufus, hence the error. If GRUB were producing releases on a timely basis, these kind of issues wouldn't happen, as Ubuntu would just pick the latest and wouldn't have to apply custom pacthes, but, sadly, the GRUB project chooses NOT to release when they have more than enough changes to.

Comment: Note however that, because patched GRUB 2.06 version is incompatible with a vanilla GRUB 2.06 version, and it's impossible to detect what patches a GRUB 2.06 bootloader executable has had applied, this change may result in older Ubuntu versions now producing the `452: out of range pointer` error when using Rufus 4.0... In that case, you may want to try with Rufus 3.22 instead of Rufus 4.0 which you can download [here](https://rufus.ie/downloads/).

Comment: @Akeo real world confirmation attempting to install Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 today. Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error when I installed Ubuntu 22.04 using Rufus latest version 4. After much digging I found this has to do with that mentioned Rufus latest version 4 bug. Following suggestions of Rufus dev in this thread, https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues/2233, I finally fix it by installing it with old Rufus version 3.13

Comment: Just to confirm R 3.13 worked for me too. R 4 did not.

Comment: I confirm as well: R3.13 works, R4.0 gives the same error.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the exact same issue, while trying to boot Ubuntu from a USB-Key on a Lenovo Tiny Box.
After not finding any relatable Info just like you did, I tried to Check how my boot devices were listed.
Turns out my Box tried to boot in Legacy mode, and choosing UEFI-Mode made it work like a charm.
Maybe that'll work for you aswell.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm using a mini-ITX mobo, no issues with the boot sequence/mode. I solved the problem by installing Ubuntu 22.10 and then upgrading to 23.04. It seems the issue lies in GRUB, rather than the system itself.

Comment: Thanks! You brought me back from the verge of insanity!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by installing the previous version (22.10) and then updating to the latest (23.04).
Unfortunately, I'm not knowledgeable enough to even guess the reason behind this error.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. In my case, I just needed my data stored in the VDI. I simply extracted the VDI file using 7Zip on my Host machine. Later created a new VM and through shared folders copied my data into my new VM. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think I am encountering this same issue. I see a top reply above making me think I am seeing this error because the Win10 system is UEFI, but my USB bootable is listed under Legacy. Not sure how to fix this, so I'll have to search around. I used Rufus to make this a UEFI bootable, so a bit confused at this point. (Dell XPS laptop)

Comment: My Solution:
Press F12 do get to the Boot Options
Go to BIOS
General
Boot Sequence
Make sure Boot List Option is selected as UEFI
Select Add Boot Option
Add your USB from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure this out? Think this has to do with the system being UEFI, but my Dell XPS is showing the USB under Legacy Boot Options and I'm ignorantly clicking it.

My Solution:
Press F12 do get to the Boot Options
Go to BIOS
General
Boot Sequence
Make sure Boot List Option is selected as UEFI
Select Add Boot Option
Add your USB from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Rufus 4.0.2035
Created in MBR failed
Created in GPT DD success
Was able to write the image with the current version of rufus in DD no issue with booting from usb or the install