# 452: Out of range pointer: 0xda657020 Aborted. Press any key to exit

Tags: lubuntu

My PC specs in the case you need them:

- CPU   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3667U CPU @ 2.00GHz   2.00 GHz
- RAM   8.00 GB (7.89 GB available)
- GPU probably integrated graphics or smth

I'm trying to install Lubuntu 22.04.2 LTS to my USB stick so I can get a second OS, but when i boot with it, it says "452: Out of range pointer: 0xda657020 Aborted. Press any key to exit." I tried if there's anything wrong with the files, checked that nothing is missing, nothing was missing.

I searched up "452: Out of range pointer: 0xda657020 Aborted." But only similar errors come up, not the exact one.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Rufus developer here.

The problem is that, due to lack of timely releases, GRUB 2.06 has become a complete *shit show*, if you pardon my language, because what Ubuntu identifies as "GRUB 2.06" in Ubuntu 23.04 and what Ubuntu identifies as "GRUB 2.06" in Ubuntu 22.04 are actually two very different versions of the vanilla GRUB 2.06 source, with a bunch of completely different **incompatible** patches applied, since the Ubuntu folks, like everybody else, have  understandably become *annoyed* at the lack of a GRUB release since 2.06, two years ago, and have taken it upon themselves to cherry pick important fixes and improvements from the upcoming version of GRUB to apply them to the one they use for Ubuntu ISOs.

Oh, and just to clarify, GRUB is the bootloader that displays the initial Ubuntu selection menu and ultimately produces the `452: Out of range pointer` error you get...

The problem is that, to make a GRUB based media boot for BIOS/Legacy, Rufus needs to install a replacement for GRUB 2.06 (we can't get one from the ISO itself). But since the Ubuntu folks did not apply a version suffix to differentiate Ubuntu 22.04.2's GRUB 2.06 from Ubuntu 23.04's GRUB 2.06, we currently have no choice but to pick **one** GRUB 2.06, and unfortunately, the GRUB 2.06 that works for Ubuntu 23.04, which is what Rufus 4.0 uses, does produces a `452: out of range pointer` when used with Ubuntu 22.04 and the GRUB 2.06 that works for Ubuntu 22.04, which is what Rufus 3.22 uses, produces a `452: out of range pointer` when used with Ubuntu 23.04 (again, these GRUB 2.06, despite allegedly being the same version, are **incompatible** with one another). Rufus does have a solid mechanism to download specific versions of GRUB as needed (so that we can install one with specific patches when required), but that only works **if** distro maintainers do their job and clearly flag their GRUB version as something that is not vanilla, by adding a suffix to the version for instance...

I'm afraid that there is currently no easy solution to address this problem in Rufus, outside forcing people to use DD, [**which, despite what many appear to think, is not a good default**](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#user-content-Why_doesnt_Rufus_recommend_DD_mode_over_ISO_mode_for_ISOHybrid_images_Surely_DD_is_better), or asking people installing Ubuntu 22.04 to use Rufus 3.22 (which uses the old non Ubuntu 23.04 incompatible version of the GRUB 2.06 bootloader) and asking people installing Ubuntu 23.04 to use Rufus 4.0 for the time being.

You can download all these various versions of Rufus from https://rufus.ie/downloads/.

The best I **might** be able to accomplish in future versions of Rufus is to use a specific GRUB 2.06 according to the *label* of the ISO (since, despite my best effort, there is no easy way to spot difference we can leverage between the GRUB binaries embedded in the Ubuntu ISOs to identify which GRUB 2.06 should be used, and we have to do the same for Fedora, so we need something that works for more than Ubuntu anyway). However, this solution will require a lot of maintenance behind the scenes and will be imperfect.

All in all, it's **users** like you who are paying the price of GRUB maintainers thinking that they don't need to release in a timely manner (unfortunately this is not the first time this has happened, as we warned them that not doing so was already a major last time a serious GRUB vulnerability was found with regards to Secure Boot), as well as Ubuntu maintainers failing to understand that, when you do apply a bunch of patches to a source, you **MUST** alter the version string report and not pretend you are using the vanilla one. That is the real problem here, because if GRUB or Ubuntu had been doing any of the above, you, and tons of other people trying to install older versions of Ubuntu on Legacy systems using Rufus, wouldn't be in this mess...

**UPDATE (2023.06.02):**

Rufus 4.1 added a workaround that should make all versions of Ubuntu work again.

If you are still experiencing this issue:

1. Please make sure that you [use Rufus 4.1 or later](https://rufus.ie).
2. If you created a drive with Rufus in the past, try <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to force Rufus to download the relevant GRUB bootloaders again.
3. If this doesn't work and you are still getting the `error 452: out of range pointer`, please open an issue in the [Rufus issue tracker](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/issues) **and make sure to indicate what ISO you are using and where you downloaded it**.

Comment: I read your arguments against cloning from an iso file to a USB boot drive. I think I understand them, but I don't agree, I think cloning is a robust and reliable method, but I don't like tools like `dd`, that do what you tell it without any questions. There should be a 'final checkpoint' where the user should be able to identify and confirm the target drive. Anyway I like your tool and appreciate your work very much even if I don't agree with everything you say, and I'm glad that you have your 'DD-mode'.

Comment: By the way, when people stop booting in BIOS mode alias CSM alias legacy mode, I hope and think that you won't need to fetch any grub components, it should work to simply extract the content of an iso file to a filesystem accepted by the computer for booting: FAT32 generally, and now many computers are willing to boot from NTFS (for example middle aged and newer Dells) and maybe also boot from exFAT ...

Comment: _"I hope and think that you won't need to fetch any grub components"_ That is correct, because the issue is that a GRUB optical BIOS bootloader can't work for USB/HDD BIOS boot, whereas a GRUB UEFI bootloader can. We only fetch GRUB components in Rufus when the user selects BIOS+UEFI. However, BIOS support is going to stay for a while, as there will always be people wanting to install Linux on legacy systems. As to using NTFS for UEFI boot, Rufus already provides a solution for that, including for systems that don't have native NTFS support. See https://github.com/pbatard/uefi-ntfs.

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few tips from
["452: out of range pointer" during installation - Why? And how to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464573/452-out-of-range-pointer-during-installation-why-and-how-to-fix-it)

1. Try different app to create your USB OS drive. Rufus has known issues
2. BIOS in UEFI-mode and not Legacy
3. Try a different desktop and once installed add Lubuntu desktop packages. Ubuntu and Kubuntu are also great choices to consider
4. DVI to HDMI or DVI to VGA type adapters can cause GPU issues. Change cables or try not to use adapters.

Let us know what worked.